# Best way to create Cloud Endpoints 2.0 app with Objectify now that Android Studio 3 doesn't have endpoints modules

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Back in Android Studio 2.0 you could just add a Cloud Endpoints 1.0 backend module and it would generate for you a sample project that used Objectify. It was very convenient.

However, Android Studio 3.0 no longer has this feature and Cloud Endpoints 2.0 requires you use IntelliJ Ultimate edition to [generate](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/create-standard) a App Engine Standard Environment project. However... IntelliJ Ultimate edition costs $500 and it doesn't appear a sample project with Objectify is created... Sigh...

So my question is, what is the best way to create a sample Cloud Endpoints project that uses Objectify? Because as of right now there appears to be no clear way from reading the documentation unless you want to shell out $500 for IntelliJ Ultimate edition.

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend) as a start. You can import it as a Gradle project to Android Studio. Adding Objectify manually shouldn't be too difficult from there.

Comment: Is there any better solution than this ? Or any news that android studio will support it again by default ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what is commented in the previous answer, if there are any doubts regarding how to use Objectify with App Engine, you can check out this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/guestbook-objectify) for integrating Objectify on a Java application.

You can run it using Maven as this:

```
mvn clean package
mvn appengine:run
```

After running it locally, you can deploy the app and check it works correctly:

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

Once you check it works and understand the code, you can integrate it with the sample app indicated in the previous answer and combine them to create your Endpoints project with Objectify.